# Is there a way to read the data from a SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) report?

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, powerbi

At my work there is a page with a bunch of SSRS reports, how would I go about accessing that data programmatically?  Currently, I am exporting the reports to excel to keep my dashboards "current".  Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: why don't you open the reports and get the t-sql that is used to load the reports and then use those queries in your excel by creating a data connection in excel to refresh the data and keep you dashboard up-to-date?

Comment: I am not sure how I would get the t-sql.  When I open a report, I just see the table view.  I have very limited permissions to the page.

Comment: The T-SQL will be in the Data source when you have the report/project open in SSDT. If you don't have permission, or aren't responsible for the reports, you'd be better off speaking to who ever is

Comment: This is really not the recommended way to extract data.

Answer (score 1):

If your SSRS report has table(s) then you can call the URL Access method as a Power BI Query (Web source).

Here's the doco:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs

Setting the &rs:Format=CSV seems the best method.  In the PBI Query Editor you can Remove Top Rows, Promote Headers etc to get the table you are after.